# java two-dimensional array out of extension

Tags: java, arrays

i have this simple code:

```
double[][] params = new double[][]{{197.0,258.0,427.0,426.0,507.0,524.0,386.0},
    {345.0,473.0,484.0,422.0,406.0,291.0,289.0}};       

for (int i = 0; i <= params.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= params[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Coordinates: " + params[i][j]); //line 29       
    }
}
```

and the error:

```
> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7    at
> com.eyecom.gen.generate_xml(gen.java:29)
```

Why do I get this exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, arrays are zero based. Here you're exceeding the array bounds. Use

```
for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < params[i].length; j++) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < params[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Coordinates: " + params[i][j]); // line 29
    }
}
```

indexes in array are from `0` to `length-1` so you don't want to use index equal to `length`.

Comment: Can downvoter explain his action? I really would like to learn where I sad something incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Change the for loop construct

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= params.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= params[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Coordinates: " + params[i][j]); //line 29               
    }
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < params[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Coordinates: " + params[i][j]); //line 29               
    }
}
```